# How do I apply existential elimination to the following Fitch proof?

Tags: logic, fitch

I am trying to prove ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y) from  [Relational Proofs](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_08.html) using the Fitch system from [Barwise and Etchemendy](https://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/site/157586374X.shtml).

I can get as far as line 5, but I cannot figure out how to apply Existential Elimination on line 6 in the Fitch system.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
1.  ∀y.∃z.loves(y,z)                      Premise
2.  ∀x.∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))   Premise
3.  ∃z.loves(y,z)                         UE: 1
4.  ∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))      UE: 2
5.  ∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))         UE: 4 OK to here
6.  loves(x,y)                            EE: 3, 5
7.  ∀y.loves(x,y)                         UI: 6
8.  ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y)                      UI:
```

My best effort is as follows:

```
1.  ∀y.∃z.loves(y,z)                   Premise
2.  ∀x.∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))  Premise
3.  ∃z.loves(a,z)                       UE: 1
4.  ∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(b,y))    UE: 2
5.  ∀z.(loves(a,z) ⇒ loves(b,a))        UE: 4
6.  loves(b,a)                          FO Con: 3,5
8.  ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y)                    FO Con 2,6
```

Note that I am using arbitrary constants instead of the free variables suggested.
This is because I do not know how to use free variables in Fitch. Also I am using First Order consequence (FO Con) instead of Existential Elimination. In short I cannot follow the Stanford Proof using the Fitch system.

Comment: From 3: ∃z.loves(y,z) you have to apply Existential Eliminationintroducing a **new** variable **a** to get loves(y,a).

Comment: But then, you have to use **a** in 5. to get loves(y,a) ⇒ loves(x,y).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tried this approach. I can start a sub proof at 3 with a new variable, but I cannot get out of the sub proof.

Comment: The second paragraph of Chapter 13 from  Barwise and Etchemendy seems to indicate that Fitch does not allow free variables in proofs.

Comment: Constants are OK in place of free vars... Call **a** a **new** constant.

Comment: Your second solution seems ok... FO Con is only a "shortcu" for ExElim after step 3 with new const **c** to get loves(a,c) followed by UE from 5 with **c** to get  loves(a,c) ⇒ loves(b,a) and finally *modus ponens*.

Comment: The crucial bit you seem to be missing, that has been pointed out by Mauro's comments, is that existential elimination, unlike universal elimination, requires you to use a _new_, previously unused constant. For this reason you'll often want to eliminate existentials before universals. That's why you can only use FO con at 6, because "b" is not a new constant and so FO con is filling in those steps in the way Mauro indicates.

Comment: Try existential elimination on 3 at line 4 before you do the additional universal eliminations.

Answer (score 2):

I have added what I think is a solution in Fitch

[image]

Any comments would be appreciated.
My attempt seems much longer than the [Stanford Proof](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_08.html) (8.3), which talks about "the power of free variables". I think I need to post another question concerning Fitch, free variables, and arbitrary constants.
I would have posted this as an edit to my original question, but being a new user I am restricted to two links

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter proof than the one provided in an answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/42928/29944 It is similar to the first 9 lines of this proof, but proceeds with universal introduction right after that.

[image]

To use the proof checker, I replaced *loves(x,y)* with *Lxy* to fit its input requirements.

Once I derived line 8 that did not have the constant *c*, I could close the subproof discharging the assumption on line 6 with existential elimination as the inference rule.  This proof also uses constants rather than free variables for existential and universal elimination.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I could not replicate your proof from line 9 on, using Fitch software. I think that Fitch needs a very specific form of universal instantiation, see an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492570/prove-reflexivity-using-fitch-software)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting from the end -- thusly work towards the target.

It is also useful to indent the proof when you introduce a new term.

If the target is a double universal, we need to introduce those from the assumption of two arbitrary terms.

```
 1.|  ∀y.∃z.loves(y,z)                      Premise
 2.|_ ∀x.∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))   Premise
 3.|  |_ [a]
 4.|  |  |_ [b]
   :  :  :
   |  |  |  loves(a,b)
   |  |  ∀y.loves(a,y)                       UI: 4-?
   |  ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y)                       UI: 3-?
```

Now to derive that `loves(a,b)` from the implication we need to eliminate two universals in the second premise with replacements [x\a] and [y\b]

```
 1.|  ∀y.∃z.loves(y,z)                      Premise
 2.|_ ∀x.∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))   Premise
 3.|  |_ [a]
 4.|  |  |_ [b]
 5.|  |  |  ∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(a,y)) UE: 2 [x\a]
 6.|  |  |  ∀z.(loves(b,z) ⇒ loves(a,b))    UE: 5 [y\b]
   :  :  :
   |  |  |  loves(a,b)
   |  |  ∀y.loves(a,y)                       UI: 4-?
   |  ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y)                       UI: 3-?
```

Thusly we come to the need to prepare the antecedent with a witness for the existential embedded in the first premise (by first eliminating the universal).

Which basically completes the proof after eliminating a universal, and the conditional, to then derive the immediate target with an existential elimination.

```
 1.|  ∀y.∃z.loves(y,z)                      Premise
 2.|_ ∀x.∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(x,y))   Premise
 3.|  |_ [a]
 4.|  |  |_ [b]
 5.|  |  |  ∀y.∀z.(loves(y,z) ⇒ loves(a,y)) UE: 2 [x\a]
 6.|  |  |  ∀z.(loves(b,z) ⇒ loves(a,b))    UE: 5 [y\b]
 7.|  |  |  ∃z.loves(b,z)                    UE: 1 [y\b]
 8.|  |  |  |_ [c] loves(b,c)                Ass: 
 9.|  |  |  |  loves(b,c) ⇒ loves(a,b)      UE: 6 [z\c]
10.|  |  |  |  loves(a,b)                    ⇒E: 8,9
11.|  |  |  loves(a,b)                       EE: 7,8-10
12.|  |  ∀y.loves(a,y)                       UI: 4-11
13.|  ∀x.∀y.loves(x,y)                       UI: 3-12
```

Comment: Thanks for your proof. It is shorted than mine and also works with Fitch software.